# 5008 error in flash cs4 as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

HI i try to add a class in my project and show me this error "the name of definition "Box" does not reflect the location of this file.Pleas change the definition's name inside this file, or rename the file."
What can i do for that the name is correct in class and in folder!
Is anybody help me please.......

Answer (score 1):

The name of the file should be same as the name of the one-and-only public class in that file. For example, `Box.as` can contain only one public class by the name `Box` (the file can have other non-public classes though).

Also, the location of the file should match the `package` statement in the file. If the package is set to `org.cidev.graphics`, the file should be placed at the relative folder `org/cidev/graphics` (relative to the root folder of the source).

```
//File org/cidev/graphics/Box.as
package org.cidev.graphics {

  public class Box {
  }

  class AnotherPrivateClass {
    //this won't be accessible outside this file
  }
}
```